# Laravel redirect to [https] not [http]

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me out for below question.

I am using laravel version 5.

1) In pagination,

```
{!! $list->appends($form)->links() !!}
```

2) In redirect action,

```
return redirect()->action('toute@method', [$testId]);
```

Both redirect to me [https] not [http].

Thank you !

Comment: Why on earth would you want to strip HTTPS

Comment: You could take a loot at `.htaccess` redirects rules.

Comment: Look to yours `.env` file.
check for `APP_URL`

Comment: Are you using a local testing environment with chrome and a .dev domain? Then chrome forces you to use use a secure connection. More information can be found [here](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by adding below line in **Middleware**.

```
$request->server->set('HTTPS', 'off');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is worth a try.

In your `AppServiceProvider.php` you could add this:

```
\URL::forceSchema('http');
```

Hope it helps.